# How to offset Date to the beginning of the month?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data frame that goes more or less like this:

```
Date    x   y   z
1998-01-30  000445  Abbey National Plc  2.24455118179321
1998-01-30  001097  Mytravel Group  1.55792689323425
```

The 'Date' column is datetime64[ns] type and I would like to offset the 'Date' column so that my date would shift to the beginning of the month, so this should go like this:

```
df['New Date'] = df['Date'].offsets.MonthBegin()
```

But returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'offsets'
```

Why so? a single df column is series, right?

```
type(df['Date'])
Out[83]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: I believe you need to apply this to a `tseries` like [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
df['New_date'] = df.set_index('Date').index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('D')
```

This assumes that `Date` is already a datetime object. If it isn't, then first convert using.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

It's not essential, but good practice to add an underscore in between column names.
So `New_date` instead of `New date`. Possibly make this lowercase also.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_period'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? This works on `'0.25.3'`

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right. I cleared everything out and started from scratch. Your method seems to work correctly.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help